# datepart from a filename

Tags: bash, csv, awk

my bash scripting skills are in their infancy, however i need to get the date parts from a filename please...

file looks like this: `filename.csv.20160229_015007`

obviously this file is filename.csv.yyyymmdd_hhmmss..  what i need in an ideal world, is separate variables for year, month, day, hour, minute, second

i will then use these later in my script.. I've had a play with the cut and also awk command with little success, still playing though.

Ty.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally I've used `cut` for this as I find it pretty explicit. Try:

```
$ fn="filename.csv.20160229_015007"
$ dt=$( echo "${fn}" | cut -d. -f3 )
$ echo "${dt}"
20160229_015007
$ year=$( echo "${dt}" | cut -c1-4 )
$ month=$( echo "${dt}" | cut -c5-6 )
$ day=$( echo "${dt}" | cut -c7-8 )
$ hour=$( echo "${dt}" | cut -c10-11 )
$ minute=$( echo "${dt}" | cut -c12-13 )
$ second=$( echo "${dt}" | cut -c14-15 )
$ echo "${year} ${month} ${day} ${hour} ${minute} ${second}"
2016 02 29 01 50 07
```

Or, if you're using Bash and you don't fancy using `cut`, a more compact way is:

```
$ dt=${fn##*.}
$ echo "${dt}"
20160229_015007
$ year="${dt:0:4}"
$ month="${dt:4:2}"
$ day="${dt:6:2}"
$ hour="${dt:9:2}"
$ minute="${dt:11:2}"
$ second="${dt:13:2}"
$ echo "${year} ${month} ${day} ${hour} ${minute} ${second}"
2016 02 29 01 50 07
```

Comment: this looks to be the badger, will test in the morning.. ty!

Comment: If by "the badger" you mean something that looks cute and harmless but will bite you in the ass at the first opportunity then yes, you are correct - that is what this is :-). Always quote your shell variables unless you have a very specific purpose in mind by leaving them unquoted and fully understand all of the implications of doing so. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/133219

Comment: hmmm.. what do you mean by quote? I followed the link and read a bit but it still wasn't overly clear - sorry for the simple q

Comment: He means that you should place quotes round your variables to ensure that the shell doesn't expand them into something you weren't expecting. (i.e. `dt="${fn##*.}"`) He's right, though I gave the above only as a specific example of how to split a bash date string. The extent to which it may cause a vulnerability not to quote variables depends very much on the source of your input string, but I would say in general that it's a good idea to do it. It will not change output of the example above - at least in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ fname="filename.csv.20160229_015007"

$ set -f # turn off globbing since we're about to use an unquoted variable

$ arr=( ${fname//[._]/ } )

$ echo "${arr[0]}"
filename
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
csv
$ echo "${arr[2]}"
20160229
$ echo "${arr[3]}"
015007

$ echo "${arr[2]:0:4}"
2016
$ echo "${arr[2]:4:2}"
02
$ echo "${arr[2]:6:2}"
29
$ echo "${arr[3]:0:2}"
01
$ echo "${arr[3]:2:2}"
50
$ echo "${arr[3]:4:2}"
07
```

Comment: had make this longer than 15 chars - globbing??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: apologies, was replying on my phone and trying to keep it short.. i don't understand the comment "# turn off globbing since we're about to use an unquoted variable" - what is globbing?

Comment: The process by which metacharacters in text get expanded by shells into file names. Like if you do `ls *`, globbing is what converts `*` into the list of files in your current directory. It's an extremely important part of shell programming and the cause of many unexpected bugs in shell scripts. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it by getting a string to use with the `date` utility, if you have access to it.

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=`echo filename.csv.20160229_015007|
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[._]";timestring=""}{
  timestring=substr($4,1,2); 
  for(i=1;i<3;i++){
     timestring=timestring":"substr($4,i*2+1,2);
  }
  system("date --date='"'"'"$3" "timestring"'"'"' +'"'"'%y %m %d %H %M %S'"'"'");
}'`

read -a arr <<<"$DATE"

echo "$DATE"

echo "${arr[@]}"

year="${arr[0]}"
month="${arr[1]}"
day="${arr[2]}"
hour="${arr[3]}"
minute="${arr[4]}"
second="${arr[5]}"

echo year="$year"
echo month="$month"
echo day="$day"
echo hour="$hour"
echo minute="$minute"
echo second="$second"
```

diagnostic prints are included.